Does Exploration Percentage decrease when chests relock?
According to the Genshin Impact wiki,

Chests that are unlocked by defeating enemies that respawn will be locked again when the enemies respawn.

Opening such chests increase their area's exploration percentage, but does it go back down when they relock?

Ehm.... when they're opened, they cannot relock. Because they've been ... opened.

@ChrᴉzremembersMonica - So is the Wiki wrong? Those chests my quote talks about don't relock and refill? Or they don't exist?

I assume the exploration progress counts opened chests rather than openable chests? i.e. neither a chest locked by monsters nor a chest with its monster guards defeated but not opened count towards exploration progress, its only when the chest is opened that it adds to the tally. I know encounter points are granted for opening the chest, if you unlock but don't open the chest and wander away you don't the points. Pretty sure the chest counter in the achievements only goes up when a chest is opened, not when it is unlocked, not 100% sure this is correct but it makes intuitive sense

No because simply unlocking a chest does not increase exploration progress.
Locked in this context refers to chests with the red magic circle around them, which requires either defeating monsters or completing a puzzle to unlock.

The article means that if you leave the chest alone (i.e. don't open it) after unlocking it, it will relock once the monsters respawn and you will need to defeat the monsters again. In short the article makes a distinction between unlocking and opening a chest, and only opening the chest will increase your exploration progress, after which it will not respawn.

Ooh, possibly. If no one else assumes my interpretation, then this does make sense and will accept in a few days or something.
